# Cross/Multiple tab communication during login

Tags: session, authentication, web, authorization, local-storage

In implementation of Login, I want to make sure if a user is already logged in one tab of the browser and opens the same web site in another tab, he gets redirected to homepage rather than the log in page. It's an ideal scenario as it happens in all the web site. I am achieving the same by storing logged in unique user token in local storage. Is it the best way to achieve it? Kindly guide! is it safe? If not how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just consider everything on the client as tainted or possibly manipulated.
So basically you should always check on the server side if the client has a valid session and only then deliver the homepage to it.

I would use a cookie set by the server side - just a random id bound to the actual client session on the server.
So the client could mess with that, but would have a hard time to guess another (also random) session id.
The cookie should be cleared by the server if the user logs out.

Then I would check on every call if he has a valid session id and if not directly send him to the login page by a redirect. Additionally you could then send him from the login page to the homepage whenever he is already logged in.